# Adding FTP user via bash script issue

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ftp, sh

I have a .sh file (lets say adduser.sh) that is executed via a cronjob that contains the commands to create an FTP user.

The adduser.sh file looks like so...

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /var/www/vhosts/domain/path;
useradd -d /var/www/vhosts/domain/path -ou <uid> -g <group> -s /bin/false <username>;
echo <password> | passwd <username> --stdin;
```

Now here is my problem. If I run it directly through SSH using...

```
sh adduser.sh
```

...no problems and it works as intended.

But if I let the cronjob run it the directory is created but the user is not added.

What gives?

Comment: On every line of code, redirect the stderr and stdout to a file and after the cron job fails, check that file for errors.  It may be a permission issue or a environment variable issue like PATH.

Comment: And how exactly would I do that? Sorry, im a bit of a noob when it comes to Linux. Hard stuff but loving it.

Comment: Add a `MAILTO=youraddress@example.com` to the top of your cron job to get the results of jobs (assuming mail is set up), or have a look at the mailbox for root (perhaps `/var/mail/root`).  The errors shown will tell you what is wrong.  If you don't have a text email client (like [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/), for example), you can `less /var/mail/root` to see what's there.

Comment: I actually just added my email in Plesk so that I get notified on all cronjobs. I am getting the following error...

adduser: command not found
passwd: Unknown user name '<username>'.

I will try adduser and see what happens.

Comment: Correction on that error, it was useradd: command not found
passwd: Unknown user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this simply adding **/usr/bin/** to the useradd function.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /var/www/vhosts/domain/path;
/usr/bin/useradd -d /var/www/vhosts/domain/path -ou <uid> -g <group> -s /bin/false <username>;
echo <password> | passwd <username> --stdin;
```

Thanks everyone for helping me get on the right track. Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, there is an alternative to `useradd` known as `adduser`. In Debian or Ubuntu, `adduser` is a perl script and performs sequential functions like create the user using `adduser`, assign it to a group, create home directory etc.

As per `adduser` man page-

> `adduser` and `addgroup` are friendlier front ends to the low level tools
>   like useradd, groupadd and usermod programs, by default choosing
>   Debian policy conformant UID and GID values, creating a home directory
>   with skeletal configuration, running a custom script, and other
>   features.

In Fedora, RedHat, and CentOS, `adduser` is just a symbolic link to `useradd`.

```
[root@hobbit ~]# which /usr/sbin/adduser
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2012-09-20 20:20 /usr/sbin/adduser -> useradd
```

If you are on any on the above OS then you can try `adduser` redirect `2>` to a `add_user.log` file and check the file to see if something goes wrong.

Comment: As with my try above get the same error... adduser: command not found passwd: Unknown user name '<username>'.